# Julia: Appending an element to a 2-D array

Tags: arrays, julia

How do I append an element to a 2-D array in Julia? I tried using `push!`

```
test = [1 2; 3 4]
push!(test, [8 9])
```

but I got the following error

```
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching push!(::Array{Int64,2}, ::Array{Int64,2})
Closest candidates are:
  push!(::Any, ::Any, ::Any) at abstractarray.jl:2158
  push!(::Any, ::Any, ::Any, ::Any...) at abstractarray.jl:2159
  push!(::Array{Any,1}, ::Any) at array.jl:920
  ...
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at none:0
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by concatenating the additional rows.

```
test = [1 2; 3 4]
vcat(test, [8 9])
```

Comment: very insightful